# how to print all date bettween 2 dates

Tags: php

I'm sure if it possible so I consult with you.

I have 2 string that contain dates: d/m/Y

for instant:

```
$from_date= "17/10/2018";

$till_date = "20/10/2018";
```

is it possible to print the total number of day between those dates and also to print the dates?

For instant:

4 days

```
17/10/2018

18/10/2018

19/10/2018

20/10/2018
```

Comment: It is possible, what doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
$start = new DateTime('2018-10-17');
$end = new DateTime('2018-10-20');

while ($start <= $end) {
    echo $start->format('Y-m-d') . '<br>';
    $start->modify('+1 day');
}
```

Comment: this does not use the date format as specified in the question - doing so would cause this to bomb

Answer (score 1):

Using the `DateTime` class and it's associated method `createFromFormat` to translate the supplied dates to a workable format and adding a `DateInterval` makes this fairly straigtforward

```
$int    = new DateInterval('P1D');
$start  = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y','17/10/2018')->sub( $int );
$end    = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y','20/10/2018');


while( $start < $end )echo $start->add( $int )->format('Y-m-d') . '<br />';
```

outputs:

```
2018-10-17
2018-10-18
2018-10-19
2018-10-20
```

To obtain the specified output format change the `format` string as supplied to the format method - ie: `->format('d-m-Y')`

Comment: If till_date is 20/10/2018, why output 2018-10-21?

Comment: @BhaskarJain - good point, corrected the above to correctly output from start to specified end dates

Answer (score 0):

> just for helping to implement .is not full description

you can use this code

```php
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($from_date. ' + 1 days'));
```

for next day until arrive at the `$till_date`

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can try something like this :

```
$arr = array("17-10-2018", "18-10-2018", "19-10-2018", "20-10-2018");
$countDateBetweenDates = 0;

foreach ($arr as $value) {

    if (strtotime($value) > strtotime("17-10-2018") && strtotime($value) < strtotime("20-10-2018")) {

        $countDateBetweenDates = $countDateBetweenDates + 1;
    }       

}

echo $countDateBetweenDates;
```

Comment: and if you want use the format : 17/09/2017 you can change for 17-09-2017. strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", "20/10/2018"));